# cp panel entry assets element sorting

Tags: entries, assets, control-panel, sorting

Is it possible to add an element to the existing assets list and make it sortable

i need it because i have made some modifications that allow to group 2 assets together so generally i now have a list of normal assets added to entries and grouped ones that are wrapped in a div with class pair

i can sort the assets within pairs and assets outside any of the pairs but not the pairs themselves.

[image: an example]

In the screenshot you can see that there are two pairs with the purple background. Would it be possible to somehow add them to the sorting flow so i could drag them around as well?

Comment: Never mind the question, found out how to do this. If anyone else needs something similar then adding the new {{ jsClass }}( part of input template into a function and calling it after extra elements are added also makes them sortable

Comment: Would you mind entering that as an official answer, @Gints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do this. If anyone else needs something similar then adding the new `{{ jsClass }}` part of input template into a function and calling it after extra elements are added also makes them sortable.